# Router config page not opening

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ftp

(I’ve moved this question across from the Networking Engineering StachExchange.)

I have two problems that I think are related, but I’m not certain. I welcome advice on where to post my queries if this is not an appropriate forum.

I can’t access my router configuration page from my PC, but I can access it from other devices on the same network. I can see from running ipconfig that the default gateway is 192.168.1.1, and I can access the settings page through Chrome on my Android device and another PC. On my PC I sometimes get prompted for the username and password, but the page never loads. In Chrome it eventually asks if I want to kill it, and in Firefox and Edge it also fails to load. Internet access hasn’t been a problem, and I have rebooted multiple times, switched the router and modem on and off, rebooted them, reset the router and had it reconfigured by my ISP, all to no avail.

I first noticed the problem about a month ago.

The router is a Cisco Linksys E900. I’ve downloaded the manual but don’t see anything that allows for a scenario in which the configuration page doesn’t load. I’ve also tried running Linksys Connect to reconfigure the network when I reset the router, but it never completed the configuration successfully.

I became aware of the problem when I failed to connect via FTP to a website I administer and was looking for solutions. In FileZilla the log reads:

```
Status: Resolving address of grahamvdr.com
Status: Connecting to 196.41.123.237:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (196,41,123,237,152,106)
Command:    MLSD
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
```

I have contacted the web hosts and they have said that there is no problem on their side, and they whitelisted my public IP. I can access the site via the cPanel, and I can access another site I administer with the same hosts via FileZilla.

If I try running the Network configuration wizard in FileZilla I get the following:

```
Connecting to probe.filezilla-project.org
Response: 220 FZ router and firewall tester ready
USER FileZilla
Response: 331 Give any password.
PASS 3.14.0
Response: 230 logged on.
Checking for correct external IP address
Retrieving external IP address from http://ip.filezilla-project.org/ip.php
Checking for correct external IP address
IP 197.211.219.227 bjh-cbb-cbj-cch
Response: 200 OK
PREP 57083
Response: 200 Using port 57083, data token 1922781548
PORT 197,211,219,227,222,251
Response: 501 IP Mismatch. Tainted by router or firewall.
PORT command tainted by router or firewall.
Connection closed
```

FileZilla FTP Client is listed in the allowed apps and features of my Windows firewall for public and private connections.

Running ipconfig gave me the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Graham>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 5:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : zol.co.zw
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f850:7853:6428:9561%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Tunnel adapter isatap.zol.co.zw:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : zol.co.zw

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:2c45:ca1e:3a2c:2444
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2c45:ca1e:3a2c:2444%2
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

C:\Users\Graham>
```

The above info applies to my home network, though I have the same problems in FileZilla from my work network.

I ran a Windows network troubleshooter and found that there are multiple devices on the network performing NAT. (I’m on my work network now, so can’t check the exact wording or details. I can confirm later if it would be useful.)

I have been able to access the router configuration page and my site via FTP on this PC in the past, though perhaps not since I upgraded to Windows 10 from 8.1. I can’t be sure when I last had a successful connection and what settings have changed since then.

Is there any other information that would be useful?

Comment: While at home can you ping 192.168.1.1? Do you use any extensions like Hola or antivirus with internet protection/filtering?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Linef4ult. If I ping 192.168.1.1 I get:

`C:\Users\Graham>ping 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms`

I’m using Avira Anitvirus Pro with Browser Safety and Identity Safeguard.

Comment: Argh, sorry for the horrible formatting. Should I be adding responses like that as an answer instead of a comment?

I’m looking at the Avira settings, trying to see if anything looks like it could be causing my problems. I don’t think I have any other software that could be interfering.

Comment: I’ve tried turning off the Firewall through Avira, and I get the same errors in FileZilla, both when trying to connect to the remote server and when running the Network Configuration Wizard.

Comment: You can add code/output like that to your question using the edit function and the code button, makes it prettier but no stress. IP is responsive so its something software wise on your PC intercepting 21/80/443.

Comment: Start in safe mode with networking and test access to the router: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7

Comment: I disabled web protection in Avira (thanks to this suggestion: https://answers.avira.com/en/question/avira-pros-web-protection-feature-prevents-netgear-router-interface-to-work-nighthawk-x4-42324) and I can now access the router configuration page. (Yay!) I’m still having the same problems with FileZilla, though.